# How do I install Catlateral Damage?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, games, tar

It is [this](http://www.catlateraldamage.com/play) game. The download is a `.tar.gz` file and doesn't contain any Installation files. Need some help.

Answer (score 1):

It does contain the Linux directory. In there are two binaries and a data directory.

Unpack the tarball:

```
tar xvf CatlateralDamage_v4.0a_Linux.tar.gz
```

Change to the new directory and the binaries executable:

```
cd Linux
chmod u+x "Catlateral Damage - v4.0a.x86"
```

or the other one if your system is 64bit.