# How to install tar.gz file

Tags: games, software-installation, tar

Trying to install Catlateral Damage using the usual extracting and installing commands on the terminal, but it keeps tossing me annoying errors. Probably missing something obvious. Both the archive and the file are on my desktop. Note: the file created by extracting the archive starts out named the same, but then switches to "Linux". I tried renaming it CatlateralDamage too.

```
rachael@rachael-desktop:~$ cd /home/rachael/desktop/catlateraldamage
bash: cd: /home/rachael/desktop/catlateraldamage: No such file or directory
rachael@rachael-desktop:~$ cd /home/rachael/desktop/catlateral damage
bash: cd: /home/rachael/desktop/catlateral: No such file or directory
rachael@rachael-desktop:~$ cd /home/rachael/desktop/catlateraldamage
bash: cd: /home/rachael/desktop/catlateraldamage: No such file or directory
rachael@rachael-desktop:~$ cd /home/rachael/desktop/catlateraldamage_v4.1a_linux.tar.gz
bash: cd: /home/rachael/desktop/catlateraldamage_v4.1a_linux.tar.gz: No such file or directory
rachael@rachael-desktop:~$ tar -xzf catlateraldamage_v4.1a_linux.tar.gz
tar (child): catlateraldamage_v4.1a_linux.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
rachael@rachael-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install catlateraldamage
[sudo] password for rachael: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package catlateraldamage
rachael@rachael-desktop:~$ cd /home/rachael/desktop/linux 
bash: cd: /home/rachael/desktop/linux: No such file or directory
rachael@rachael-desktop:~$ tar -zxvf CatlateralDamage_v4.1a_Linux.tar.gz
tar (child): CatlateralDamage_v4.1a_Linux.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
rachael@rachael-desktop:~$
```

Comment: what was the path to the catlateraldamage_v4.1a_linux.tar.gz file?

Comment: it's sitting on my desktop...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these commands,

```
cd ~/Desktop
tar -xzvf CatlateralDamage_v4.1a_linux.tar.gz
```

Comment: d'oh >.< didn't realize it's case-sensitive. now the tarball's unwound. what's next?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file

Comment: well, now i'm in the Linux directory, but ./configure doesn't work. what am i missing?

Comment: post the ouptut of `ls`

Comment: rachael@rachael-desktop:~/Desktop/Linux$ ls

Catlateral Damage - v4.1a_Data  Catlateral Damage - v4.1a.x86_64

Catlateral Damage - v4.1a.x86

Comment: if it was a directory then go inside it by using `cd` command,and then run ls command.

Comment: i did. the stupid comment box keeps reformatting it. it said "Catlateral Damage-v4.1a_Data", "Catlateral Damage-v4.1a.x86.64", "Catlateral Damage -v4.1a.x86", all on separate lines

Comment: where did you download that tar.gz file?

Comment: http://www.catlateraldamage.com/play click on the "linux" link

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/418088/how-do-i-install-catlateral-damage

Comment: that... did nothing that i can tell. "rachael@rachael-desktop:~/Desktop/Linux$ chmod u+x "Catlateral Damage - v4.1a.x86_64"

Comment: post the output of `ls -l` to pastebin.com and provide the link here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Qreu5Ncb

Comment: `ls -l` command and also your ubuntu is 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6ECQ3jYn not entirely sure

Comment: what was the output of `uname -m`?

Comment: that would be i686

Comment: then run `sudo chmod +x "Catlateral Damage - v4.1a.x86"` and then `./"Catlateral Damage - v4.1a.x86"`

Comment: gah. well, it worked and launched the game, unfortunately it then turned the screen black and i had to escape out of it to shut down all my other programs. now i don't know how to launch it again ;.;

Comment: go into the directory and then run `./"Catlateral Damage - v4.1a.x86"`.And don't forget to accept my answer.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Please don't encourage users to post to pastebin  or provide output in  comments. **The question should be edited instead to add more information.**

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /home/rachael/Desktop
```

then

```
 tar -zxvf CatlateralDamage_v4.1a_Linux.tar.gz
```

read [this](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/how-to-open-a-tar-file-in-unix-or-linux/) for more info

Comment: D for desktop would be in caps.

Comment: no joy. same errors. this is where i got the file from: http://www.catlateraldamage.com/play click on the "linux" link for the tar.gz
d'oh >.< didn't realize it's case-sensitive. now the tarball's unwound. what's next?